# Как достать из XYChart значения x и y?

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть серия XYChart, которая заполняется при помощи цикла. Хотел был сделать отдельный цикл, который уже достает из этой серии отдельно x и y.

```html
XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series<>();
    ObservableList<XYChart.Data> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    
    for (double i = 0; i < 360; i += 0.5) {
                double radian = i / 57.3;
                double ro = 2 * a * (1 - Math.cos(radian));
                double x1 = ro * Math.cos(radian);
                double y1 = ro * Math.sin(radian);
                list.add(new XYChart.Data(x1, y1));
            }
            series.setData(list);
            chart_zone.getData().addAll(series);
```

Comment: Хех, спасибо, получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо получить ваш `double`.
Для этого сделайте так

```
double x=(double)((XYChart.Data)series.getData().get(0)).getXValue();
double y=(double)((XYChart.Data)series.getData().get(0)).getYValue();
```

Первоисточник, конечно же [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html).

Из `series.getData()` вы получаете ObservableList, откуда берете первый элемент и приводите его к типу `XYChart.Data`, откуда вы берете значение вашего `X` и `Y` и приводите его к `double`